# Declare an array of (nullable) doubles?

Tags: c#

I have this declaration:

```
double?[] x = 0;
```

I don't know how should I declare the zero because it seems that this is not the right way.

It says:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'double?[]'

I have searched on the internet for a solution but everything that I have found didn't help me. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you want to do? `double?[]` declares an **array** (`[]`) of nullable doubles. If you only want a single double it's `double x = 0` or nullable `double? x = 0`. If you want to initialize the array it's `double?[] arr = new double?[size];`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Compiller speaks, that try assign to whole array one value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
double a = 0; // single double
double? b = 0; // single nullable double
double[] c = new double[] { 0 }; // array with a single double
double?[] d = new double?[] { 0 }; // array with a single nullable double
```

Note that `0` here is being *treated* as a double literal; more generally, though - add a period or a `D`; `0.0` or `0D` will be assumed to be a double, so:

```
var e = 0; // single int32
var f = 0.0; // single double
var g = 0D; // single double
var h = new[] { 0D }; // array with a single double
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast an integer to an array of doubles. This cannot work.
To declare an array do this:

```
double?[] x = {0, 0};
```

The compiler will cast the integer zero to a double.

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring an array of (nullable) doubles. You cannot set an array as such.

If you just want a single value the following is perfectly valid:

```
double? x = 0;
```

An array is a bit different, these are multiple numbers. So you need to initialize it as an array first.

```
double?[] x = new double?[] { 0 };
```

*Keep in mind that the above will make an array of size 1.*

As for the nullable part, are you expecting the variable to be NULL at any point? If not it would be advisable to use a normal `double` instead of the nullable version.